# Always finding nil when checking Double in Swift

Tags: swift

I've got the following code:

```
//create an NSURL
    let url = NSURL(string: self.urlString)

    //fetch the data from the url
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        //If the retrieved information is a JSON Object, and can be treated as an NSArray...
        if let jsonObj = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSObject) {

            let data = jsonObj.value(forKey: "pendingloads") as! NSArray

            for item in data {

                if let itemObject = item as? NSObject {

                    print("Tons value1: \(itemObject.value(forKey: "tons")!)")
                    let tons = itemObject.value(forKey: "tons") as? Double ?? nil
                    print("Tons value2: \(String(describing: tons))")
```

I'm doing this because I have it's possible to receive null from this data. My issue is that I always receive a double value (when the item returns one) in the first print, but nil in the second. Is it because the value of itemObject.value(forKey: "tons") is Optional?

I've attempted to force unwrap the value, but it then breaks when it is null. I need it to be nullable, but I've had trouble doing it in every documented way. I know there's a very simple answer to this, but I just haven't found it yet. Any help would be very appreciated.

The relevant JSON:

```
}   
   "pendingloads": [
   {
      "comment": "Test Comment",
      "hauler": "Test Hauler",
      "logs": [
          {
             "coords": "(25.123456, -120.123456)",
             "type": "auth",
             "timestamp": "2019-04-04 10:52:1554393131",
             "device_id": "DEVICE-ID-DEVICE-ID-DEVICEID"
           },
           {
             "coords": "(25.123456, -120.123456)",
             "type": "update",
             "timestamp": "2019-04-08 13:38:1554748736",
             "device_id": "DEVICE-ID-DEVICE-ID-DEVICEID"
            }
       ],
       "tons": "12.800",
       "load_id": 23,
       "requires_correction": false,
       "trailer_drop": true,
       "gross": "25600.000",
       "contract_id": 3679,
       "scaleticket": "2134098",
       "destination": "TEST DESTINATION",
       "sale_id": 3961,
       "tare": "0.000",
       "net": "25600.000",
       "cull": "157.000",
       "product": "Test Product",
       "operator_id": 2674,
       "hauler_id": 617,
       "timestamp": "2019-04-08 18:38:1554766680",
       "driver": "Terry",
       "ticket": 250,
       "product_id": 3172,
       "sale": "Test Sale",
       "trailer": "013724589"
     }
   ]
 }
```

In the hopes of improvement, here is the updated code:

```
//create a URL
    let url = URL(string: self.urlString)

    //fetch the data from the url
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let jsonObj = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject) {

            let data = jsonObj.value(forKey: "pendingloads") as! Array<AnyObject>

            for item in data {

                let itemObject = item as AnyObject
```

Comment: `?? nil` is redundant. And you are misusing `String(describing`. And you are discouraged from using `value(forKey` unless you really know and need KVC.

Comment: How do you **save** your value for key `"tons"`

Comment: @RobertDresler, I save it as an optional Double as part of a custom object directly after this code. This is an attempt to allow nulls in that object.

Comment: @vadian, I've removed the ?? nil. I had left it over from a previous attempt in case I changed it back, and it didn't seem to harm anything. The String(describing:) was added by suggestion of Xcode. I'm a little rusty right now, having worked in Java/Kotlin almost solely for the past 6 months.

Comment: If the first `print` line does not crash but the seconds prints `nil` then the value for key `tons` is clearly not a `Double`

Comment: @vadian The thing is, it does it even with Double values. For example, the first print value will be 12.800 and the second print value will be nil.

Comment: Then logically the value is `String`

Comment: Of course! That makes perfect sense. I'll go check on that. Thank you, @vadian.

Comment: Without _all_ the relevant code (e.g. showing what `itemObject` is) this question can't really get a decent answer.

Comment: @matt, I'll add that.

Comment: OMG: `as? NSObject) as NSObject??` is horrifying. Could you please add the relevant part of the JSON.

Comment: The whole code is horrifying. You are writing unreconstructed Objective-C as if it were Swift. You should not be using NSObject, JSONSerialization, NSURL, or `value(forKey:)`.

Comment: the json is incorrect , post complete 1 , or you're clipping the important part and only missed `{}` ?

Comment: @vadian, That's been fixed and the edited here. Relevant JSON added.

Comment: @matt, I'll work on updating those items. Thank you.

Comment: @Sh_Khan, I just showed one item in the JSON. I added the missing brackets.

Comment: JSON values wrapped in double quotes are always `String`. There is no exception. Keys are `String` anyway.

Comment: @vadian and matt, does this updated code at the bottom seem to be more along the correct lines?

Comment: No, a JSON value is never `AnyObject` in Swift. `if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments as? [String:Any] {` - `let data = jsonOb["pendingloads"] as! [[String:Any]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let pendingloads: [Pendingload]
}

struct Pendingload: Codable {
    let comment, hauler: String
    let logs: [Log]
    let tons: String
    let loadId: Int
    let requiresCorrection, trailerDrop: Bool
    let gross: String
    let contractId: Int
    let scaleticket, destination: String
    let saleId: Int
    let tare, net, cull, product: String
    let operatorId, haulerId: Int
    let timestamp, driver: String
    let ticket, productId: Int
    let sale, trailer: String

}

struct Log: Codable {
    let coords, type, timestamp, deviceId: String 
}
```

---

```
 let url = URL(string: self.urlString)! 

 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in 
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        let res = JSONDecoder()
        res.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let ss = try res.decode(Root.self, from:data)
        print(ss)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

}.resume()
```